# jQuery defaultValue in dropdownlist

Tags: jquery

Isn't there a defaultValue in a dropdownlist? As it is in a textbox, like this:
$('input#FromDateTextBox')[0].defaultValue;

I googled around and didn't find anything about defaultValue on dropdownlist. So what is the best way to solve this? Is it from server side add a data attr?

Because I whant to see what my default value was on page load. Even if I change the selected value in my list.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming on page load there is no `option` element with a `selected="true"` attribute, then the default option will be the first in the list:

```
var defaultOption = $('#mySelect option:first');
```

Otherwise if there was a `selected` attribute set, you can use the attribute selector:

```
var defaultOption = $('#mySelect option[selected="true"]');
```

Answer (score 0):

$("#mydropdown").val("myval")

is what you need

and for retrieving value you can use

$("#mydropdown").val()

Answer (score 0):

Set the dropdownlist default value like this:

```
$('#mySelect').find('option[value="defaultValue"]').prop('selected',true);
```